# NHibernate "Repeated column in mapping for collection" exception

Tags: exception, nhibernate, dictionary, mapping

Consider the following NHibernate mapping, and notice the commented properties. These are the same columns as the `key` and `index` column specified in the `map`. When I remove the comments (thus including the `TypeOfPart` and `UnitId` columns for the properties) I get the "Repeated column in mapping for collection" exception.

```
<map name="Parts" table="ActiveUnitParts" lazy="false">
  <key column="UnitId" />
  <index column="TypeOfPart" type="integer"/>
  <composite-element class="ActiveUnitPart">
    <property name="Id" />
    <property name="CreationDate" />
    <property name="PartInfo"/>
    <property name="Remarks"/>
    <!-- <property name="TypeOfPart" /> -->
    <!-- <property name="UnitId" /> -->
  </composite-element>
</map>
```

What I need in code is a `Dictinonary<TypeOfpart, ActiveUnitPart>`. But the problem I have is that the values for the properties `UnitId` and `TypeOfPart` aren't set in the `ActiveUnitPart` instance in the `Dictinonary<TypeOfpart, ActiveUnitPart>`.

Yes, the list of related parts of this unit is loaded, and yes the key in the dictionary is related to the right part. But I do not understand why I can not reference the `TypeOfPart` and `UnitId` to fill the properties in `ActiveUnitPart` itself as well.

How can I solve or workaround this?

Motivation of why I need this:
I must be able to work with `ActiveUnitPart`s without referencing the related `Unit` (`UnitId`)

**EDIT 1:**
I know I can intercept the setter of the `Parts` property of the `Unit` and iterate through the `Dictinonary<TypeOfpart, ActiveUnitPart>` to set the values in code, but it seems like a  `hack` and I wish to learn a more elegant `NHibernate` way of getting it done, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, just change the mapping from `column` to `formula`. The best way how to achieve that would be:

```
<property name="TypeOfPart" formula="TypeOfPart" insert="false" update="false" />
<property name="UnitId" formula="UnitId" insert="false" update="false" />
```